# 0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com takes too long time

Tags: ubuntu, networking

whenever i run command who have to connect to archive.ubuntu.com, that command takes too long time to complete it task.

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 java-common oracle-java8-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 java-common oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 272 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful/main amd64 oracle-java8-installer all 8u171-1~webupd8~0 [33.3 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful/main amd64 oracle-java8-set-default all 8u171-1~webupd8~0 [6,846 B]
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]
```

ping 8.8.8.8 :

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=62.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=67.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=58.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=71.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=71.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=60.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=49.0 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.028/61.584/71.951/7.865 ms
```

we can see above my speed is not slow .

[image: and ipv4 is :]

please help me to avoid this problem.every time i got stuck and have to wait until task completed.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. It fits better to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 13):

Your issue propably lies in the fact that the package manager tries to connect to repository via ipv6.

See this line from the log you provided:

```
0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]
```

I have faced the same issue before and I solved it by forcing pm to use ipv4 instead.

Add `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` when running `apt-get` .

If you want to make this setting premanent you should create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` in it:

`echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I was looking for the answers , i found this youtube guy and it fixed the issue for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASjtqyyLH-U               
Use this website to generate source list: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch

Take backup of your source list and create sourcelist file and add new data there.

Answer (score 3):

You can force apt to use IPV4 as below.

```
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com) is still correct at least for Ubuntu 16. To avoid IPv6 usage, which most probably causes problem, and force IPv4, just open file:

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

and uncomment line

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```